# disable on click animation to deselect choice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that does a "flyin" animation when click. But if the user clicks the button to deselect their choice i need to disable the animation. 
The class changes when they have selected their choice from ".simple-button" to ".simple-button active".

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
     $(".simple-button").on('click', function () {
          //Scroll to top if cart icon is hidden on top
          $('html, body').animate({
               'scrollBottom': $(".view-my-beds").position().top
          });
          //Select item image and pass to the function
          var itemImg = $(this).parent().find('img').eq(0);
          flyToElement($(itemImg), $('.view-my-beds'));
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How do i disable the animate when deselect their choice.

Comment: Please add the relevant html also so that we have [mcve] to run and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It my experience, it's best to add a class on click. This means we can detect if it's in use, thus - making your problem simple to solve:

```
 $('.simple-button').on('click', function ()
 {
      if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
          $('html, body').animate({
               'scrollBottom': $('.view-my-beds').position().top
          });

          var itemImg = $(this).parent().find('img').eq(0);
      } else {
          // do whatever without animation
      }
 })
```